# Segmentation fault in handlers with shared_ptr's

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, gnu

I am trying to make a proxy that works properly only for the first session in one execution of app. It catches `SIGSEGV` trying to handle the second one.

It works next way:

- client connects
- proxy connects to end server (unique connection for each session)
- proxy sends data to server, gets handled data from server and sends handled data to client
- proxy breaks connection with server and client

The problem is when we start the app and the first client tries to use proxy, it works fine (let it be clients connect to proxy consistently e.g. first one got its data, disconnection occured and only then the second one connects). But when the second one tries to connect after this, execution can not even reach the `handleAccept` and catches `SIGSEGV` in `__atomic_add` function in `atomicity.h` (I am working in Linux).

I can not understand either I make handlers incorrectly, use `shared_ptr`'s incorrectly, or both.

`run` is called once after creating `Proxy` object to make it accept and handle client connections:

```cpp
void Proxy::run() // create the very first session and keep waiting for other connections
{
    auto newSession = std::make_shared<Session>(ioService_);

    acceptor_.async_accept(
        newSession->getClientSocket(),
        [&](const boost::system::error_code &error) // handler is made according to boost documentation
        {
            handleAccept(newSession, error);
        }
    );

    ioService_.run();
}
```

`handleAccept` does almost the same thing but also makes session start transferring data between client and end server:

```cpp
void Proxy::handleAccept(std::shared_ptr<Session> session, const boost::system::error_code &error) // handle the new connection and keep waiting other ones
{
    if (!error)
    {
        session->connectToServer(serverEndpoint_);
        session->run(); // two more shared_ptr's to session are appeared here and we just let it go (details are further)
    }

    auto newSession = std::make_shared<Session>(ioService_);

    acceptor_.async_accept(
        newSession->getClientSocket(),
        [&](const boost::system::error_code &error)
        {
            handleAccept(newSession, error);
        }
    );
}
```

`Session` contains two `Socket` objects (server and client) each of which has `shared_ptr` to it. When each of them will have done all actions or some error will have occured, they `reset` their `shared_ptr`'s to session so it is deallocated.

Comment: The lambda captures by reference are suspicous -- you'll capture references to the local `newSession` variable which will be dangling after the containing function returns.  You don't need the lambda to modify the local, so why are you capturing by refernce?  Try capturing by value (change `[&]` to `[=]` in both lambdas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you use/catch local variable by reference in  handleAccept(...) ?:

```
 acceptor_.async_accept(
        newSession->getClientSocket(),
        [&](const boost::system::error_code &error)
        {
            handleAccept(newSession, error);
        }
    );
```

Would you like to use:

```
 acceptor_.async_accept(
        newSession->getClientSocket(),
        [this, newSession](const boost::system::error_code &error)
        {
            handleAccept(newSession, error);
        }
    );
```

The lambda will be run after function will be completed, and local variable newSession will be destroied before that.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing! `newSession` goes out of scope so you're left with dangling reference